# apache2 : redirect to an IP address (container's address) accoring to the url

Tags: apache, redirect, docker, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

The context :

I have a Debian with an apache2 on it. I can acces this Debian by the following ip : 192.168.12.28.

On this Debian, I have two containers with the following ips :

-172.18.0.2

-172.19.0.2

The problematic :

I want, from the outside, access to my container1 from, for exemple:
192.168.12.28/container1 
or
myDomain/container1

What I tried :

two domain : 
test1.domain.fr with the following test1.domain.fr.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test1.domain.fr

  ProxyPass / http://172.18.0.2:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://172.18.0.2:8080/
  ProxyRequests Off
</VirtualHost>
```

test2.domain.fr with the following test2.domain.fr.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test2.domain.fr

  ProxyPass / http://172.19.0.2:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://172.19.0.2:8080/
  ProxyRequests Off
</VirtualHost>
```

I have enabled the domain with :

```
a2ensite test1.domain.fr
a2ensite test2.domain.fr
```

What I have :

When I want to acces to 192.168.12.28 :
Apache's page "it works!"

When I want to acces to 192.168.12.28/test1.domain.fr or 192.168.12.28/test2.domain.fr :
The requested URL /test1(or 2).domain.fr was not found on this server.

When I want to acces to test1.domain.fr or test2.domain.fr :
cannot find test1(or 2).domain.fr

Thank you for your help and 
Sorry for my english! :-)

Edit : I'm currently searching, but I am not able to make it works for now!

Edit : my container1 is configure like : "8081:8080" and "444:443" and my container2 is configure like : "8080:8080" and "443:443"

Edit here are my docker-compose files:

First container :

```
version: '2'

services:
  php:
    build: php
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "443:443"
    volumes:
    - ./php/www:/var/www/html
```

Second Container :

```
version: '2'

services:
  php:
    build: php
    ports:
    - "8081:8080"
    - "444:443"
    volumes:
    - ./php/www:/var/www/html
```

Comment: Are the sites available from within your Debian machine? E.g.: `curl 127.0.0.1/test1.domain.fr`

Comment: Not they are not, I have the same response that from the outside

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single Docker Host (not in Swarm mode e.g.) you cannot map two containers to the same host port ... try this:

```
docker run <...> -p 3000:80 <...>   # e.g. for test1
docker run <...> -p 5000:80 <...>   # e.g. for test2
```

And adapt `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` accordingly, e.g.:

```
ProxyPass / http://172.18.0.2:3000/     # e.g. for test1
ProxyPass / http://172.19.0.2:5000/     # e.g. for test2
```

Reference (with a complete example for nginx as proxy to apache):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-bind-multiple-domains-ports-80-and-443-to-docker-contained-applications

Comment: I didn't maped my containers into the same ports, one is maped to the 8080 and 443 and the other to 8081 and 444.

Comment: Then you need to adjust your `ProxyPass` to the docker host(!) port: 8080 and 8081 (they are still the same in your given config).

Comment: No, they are not , one proxyPass is http://172.18.0.2:8080/ (container1's address) and the other one is http://172.19.0.2:8080/ (container2's address). Same port but not the same address, right?

Comment: Yes ... I got that ... but the ports are the same.